# How to wake the most people in a room?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, max, dynamic-programming

I am stuck with a problem which says that you can wake a sleeping person, and the state of this person changes from `S`, which stands for sleeping, to `.`, which stands for awake.

When you wake a person, people next to him will also wake up from sleeping, because the distance is close. For instance,  there are three people sleeping in a room. If you wake the person in the middle, then all three people will wake up, that is `SSS` becomes `...`.

However, if you wake a person who is already awake, then his status will not change. But the people next to him will be awake, that is `S.S` becomes `...`,

The problem is that given a room `s` filled with sleeping people `S` and awake people `.`. After waking `k` people, what is the maximum number of awake people in this room.

A tricky example would be `s` = `S.SSSS` and `k` = `2`.

1. waking person `s[4]`, then the room will be `S.S...`
2. waking person `s[1]`, then the room will be `......`

That is, you can make everyone in this room awake after waking person `s[4]` and person `s[1]`. Thus the answer of this example will be `6` people instead of `5`.

I wrote my solution in python by listing all the combination of index of people I could wake. Waking them and count the number of awake people.

It only works with short strings and small number of people.

I think I need some improvements on the algorithmic level. Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```py
import sys
import itertools

memo = {}

def wake(s, i):
    if i in memo: 
        return memo[i]
    s = list(s)
    for n in i:
        if n == 0:
            s[n], s[n+1] = '.', '.'
        elif n == len(s)-1:
            s[n-1], s[n] = '.', '.'
        else:
            s[n-1], s[n], s[n+1] = '.', '.', '.'
    memo[i] = s.count('.')
    return memo[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        line = f.readline()
        n, k = map(int, list(line.rstrip().split(' ')))
        line = f.readline()
        s = line.rstrip()

    ans = 0
    for i in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        temp = wake(s, i)
        if temp > ans:
            ans = temp

    print(ans)
```

For test purpose, I will put some test cases and the correct answers below.

```
Format:
n k
s
ans

5 3
.....
5

12 2
.SSSS.SS.SSS
9

7 1
..S.SS.
6

67 4
SS.S...S....SS..S..S.S.S...SS...SSS..SS.SS.SSSSS...S.S.S...S......S
48

29 2
.S.....SSSSS.SSSS...SS.SSS.SS
18

79 6
.S...SSS.SSS..SSSS.SSSSS.SS.S.SS.SS.SSSSSSS.SS...SS.S.SSS.SS.S.SS..S..S.SSS.SS.
47

41 9
.S.S...S.S.....S.SS.SS.SS.SS.S.SS.SS.....
41

91 67
...SS.SS....S...S.S.SS...SSS.SSSSSSS.....SS..S.S.SS...S..S..S.SS.......SSSSS.S.S...S.SS.S.S
91


7 97
SSSS.SS
7

276 23
SSSSSS.SSS..SSS.SS.S.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSS.S.SSS.SSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSS.S.SSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSS.S.SS.SSSSSSS.SSSSSSSS.SSS.S.
100
```

Comment: You can just give the contents of the sys.argv[1] file and ask how to improve, I believe there will be more people willing to answer your question.

Comment: @Carson Arucard Thanks for comment. That file consists of some test cases for this problem, with the format of `n`(length of the string) `k` times of flipping and `s` the string. Link to the file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XYQ9PkF7bkyTuPWcrNv7zcHktQt6jTy0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear to me. I do not understand which position you flip and why the others are flipping or not..

Comment: @Aldert Thanks for comment. I updated the statement. Hope this time it makes more sense to you.

Comment: I guess i would proceed in this order - Given string s, first find the substrings 'SSS' and 'wake' the middle person in them. Next find substrings 'SS' and wake one in each of them. Next would be 'S.S' and wake the middle one. Finally wake the remaining 'S's one by one. Follow this process until 'k' persons are woken up. I'm away atm but keen to try and code this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `dp[n][k]` be the number of `'S'` people that we woke up, if we deal with `n` first people and already woke `k` people. For `dp[n][k]` I suppose that there is no reason to wake person number `n`, because there is no person `n+1` that we can wake up (because we deal only with `n` first people), so better wake person `n-1` and also have person `n` awaked. That logic I use later.

Then, if `n <= 3` we can wake up all `n` people if we have moves, i.e. `k > 0`. If we don't have moves, then the answer is the number of already awake people.

If `n > 3`:

- if `k = 0`, then `dp[n][k] = dp[n][0] = 0`, because we didn't wake up anyone.
- if `k > 0`, then `dp[n][k] = max(dp[n - 3][k - 1] + s[n - 3 : n].count('S'), dp[n - 1][k])`. Here we handle 2 cases: if we woke person `n-1`, then `n-2, n-1, n`-th persons are awake and we lost 1 move, so we count the number of persons we just woke up (`s[n - 3 : n].count('S')`) and check the maximum number for the rest `n-3` people and `k-1` moves: `dp[n - 3][k - 1]`. If we didn't woke anybody, then we have `n`-th person if his initial state and we still have `k` moves. So the answer in this case `dp[n - 1][k]`.

The answer is `max(dp[n][k]) + s.count('.')`: `dp[n][k]` handles only the number of people that were asleep, but we woke them up. So, to get full answer we just add the number of people that were already awake.

```
ans = 0

if n <= 3:
    if k > 0:
        ans = n
    else:
        ans = s.count('.')
else:
    dp = [[0 for x in range(k + 1)] for y in range(n)]
    dp[2][1] = s[:3].count('S')
    for i in range(3, n):
        t = s[i - 3 : i].count('S')
        for j in range(1, k + 1):
            dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 3][j - 1] + t, dp[i - 1][j])

    for i in range(2, n):
        ans = max(ans, dp[i][k])

    ans += s.count('.')

print(ans)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your code, but for `s="S.SSSS.S..S"` and `k=3` it gives `11`, but it should be `10`.

Comment: @DillonDavis Daniel's dynamic programming algorithm is very brilliant, inspiring and basically correct. There is just a small overlapping problem when counting up the `S` that we woke up. In your example, array `dp` starts to get wrong probably at `dp[8][4] = 7`, where it should be `6`. Anyway, I've posted my correction of this problem below. Check it if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
import pandas as pd


def count_all(text, string):
    pos = string.find(text)
    if len(string) == 0 or pos == -1:
        return 0
    return 1 + count_all(text, string[pos+len(text):])


def calculate_ans(input_str, k)->int:
    if 'check':
        if len(input_str) == 0 or \
                (input_str.find('S') == -1 and input_str.find('.') == -1):
            return 0

        if k <= 0 or pd.isna(k):
            return input_str.count('.')

    for cur_str in ['SSS', 'S.S', 'ST.TS', 'SS', 'S']:
        count_ns = min(count_all(cur_str, input_str), k)
        if count_ns > 0:
            if cur_str != 'S.S':
                input_str = input_str.replace(cur_str, len(cur_str) * '.', int(count_ns))
            else:
                input_str = input_str.replace(cur_str, 'T.T', int(count_ns))
            k -= count_ns
        if k == 0:
            break

    return input_str.count('.') + input_str.count('T')


def carson_demo():
    df = pd.read_csv('table.csv')
    for index, (input_str, k, answer) in df.iterrows():
        ans = 0 if pd.isna(input_str) else calculate_ans(input_str, k)
        df.at[index, 'answer'] = int(ans)  # update
    df['answer'] = df['answer'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
    df['k'] = df['k'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
    df.to_csv('table.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    carson_demo()
```

table.csv (before)

```
input_str,k,answer
.....,3,
.SSSS.SS.SSS,2,
..S.SS.,1,
SS.S...S....SS..S..S.S.S...SS...SSS..SS.SS.SSSSS...S.S.S...S......S,4,
.S.....SSSSS.SSSS...SS.SSS.SS,2,
.S...SSS.SSS..SSSS.SSSSS.SS.S.SS.SS.SSSSSSS.SS...SS.S.SSS.SS.S.SS..S..S.SSS.SS.,6,
.S.S...S.S.....S.SS.SS.SS.SS.S.SS.SS.....,9,
...SS.SS....S...S.S.SS...SSS.SSSSSSS.....SS..S.S.SS...S..S..S.SS.......SSSSS.S.S...S.SS.S.S,67,
SSSS.SS,97,
SSSSSS.SSS..SSS.SS.S.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSS.S.SSS.SSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSS.S.SSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSS.S.SS.SSSSSSS.SSSSSSSS.SSS.S.,23,
```

table.csv (after)

```
input_str,k,answer
.....,3,5
.SSSS.SS.SSS,2,9
..S.SS.,1,6
SS.S...S....SS..S..S.S.S...SS...SSS..SS.SS.SSSSS...S.S.S...S......S,4,48
.S.....SSSSS.SSSS...SS.SSS.SS,2,18
.S...SSS.SSS..SSSS.SSSSS.SS.S.SS.SS.SSSSSSS.SS...SS.S.SSS.SS.S.SS..S..S.SSS.SS.,6,47
.S.S...S.S.....S.SS.SS.SS.SS.S.SS.SS.....,9,41
...SS.SS....S...S.S.SS...SSS.SSSSSSS.....SS..S.S.SS...S..S..S.SS.......SSSSS.S.S...S.SS.S.S,67,91
SSSS.SS,97,7
SSSSSS.SSS..SSS.SS.S.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSS.S.SSS.SSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSS.S.SSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSS.S.SS.SSSSSSS.SSSSSSSS.SSS.S.,23,100
```

Comment: I only have to verify some simple examples.
If there is something wrong, please give me the correct answer so that I can correct it. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I put some test cases and their answers below my question. Actually I am not very familiar with the `re` module in python, but I will look into your solution later today.

Comment: @Yan I had actually tried my own `re` solution prior to commenting, and found that it can be useful to quickly take the "low hanging fruit" regarding optimal wakes, and then you can split the problem into several smaller sub problems in many cases.

Comment: Any `\.(SSS)+\.` can be safely replaced (woke), as can `(^\.?|\.\.)SSS` and `SSS(\.\.|\.?$)` iirc.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing a small overlapping problem in Daniel's algorithm.

```
ans = 0

if n <= 3:
    if k > 0:
        ans = n
    else:
        ans = s.count('.')
else:
    dp = [[0 for x in range(k+1)] for y in range(n)]
    dp[0][1] = s[:2].count('S')
    dp[1][1] = s[:3].count('S')
    dp[2][1] = max(s[:3].count('S'), s[1:4].count('S'))
    for j in range(2,k+1):
        dp[0][j] = dp[0][1]
        dp[1][j] = dp[1][1]
        dp[2][j] = s[:4].count('S')

    for i in range(3,n-1):
        for j in range(1,k+1):
            dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-3][j-1] + s[i-1:i+2].count('S'),
                           dp[i-1][j])

    for j in range(k+1):
        dp[n-1][j] = dp[n-2][j]

    ans = dp[n-1][k]

    ans += s.count('.')

    print(ans)
```